# open in WebView instead of deep link on iOS

Tags: ios, webview, deep-linking

My iPhone app has a WebView which may sometimes show a URL registered with one of installed applications (e.g. Yelp). I want this page to open in my app. Actually, I don't care if the further links will switch to another app, but this first view should remain within our app.

I can find some app-specific workarounds, like
*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587313* for Pinterest, but I am looking fo a generic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same solution suggested in the link you posted for the app-specific workarounds, but block all links that are not http or https:

```
NSURL *url = [request URL];
if (![url.scheme isEqual:@"http"] && ![url.scheme isEqual:@"https"])
{
    return NO;
}
```

If there are other schemes you would like to support, just add them to the statement.

Comment: I may be missing something, but the author there explains that returning `NO` did not help until they added `no_auto_redirect_or_interstitial=1` to their request.

Comment: @AlexCohn the "no_auto_redirect_or_interstitial" parameter is a Pinterest parameter. If we takes the Pinterest case for example, even without the special parameter, after all the redirect requests, you'll end up with a URL which is not http or https and returning NO will prevent opening or redirecting to a deep-link URL scheme. I tested this with a Pinterest deep-linking and it works.. Are you getting different results?